# Open XML: как получить тип элемента?

Tags: c#, office, openxml, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

Мне необходимо распарсить слайды презентации PowerPoint (.pptx), а именно получить три значения для каждого элемента (shape) на слайде:

1. координату X
2. координату Y
3. Тип элемента

Нужно использовать инструмент отличный от `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`, чтобы не быть зависимым от предустановленного `Microsoft PowerPoint`.

---

**Aspose.Slides.** Да, конечно же, Google search, да и Top 20 NuGet PowerPoint Packages на первых строчках отображает `Aspose.Slides`. И он идеально подходит для наших задач, но очень дорого: ребят из Aspose говорят необходимо приобретать лицензию Developer OEM на каждого разработчика в команде, раз речь заходит о продаже продукта, разработанного на его основе. И стоит такая одна лицензия $2397.

**Open XML**. Меня предупреждали, что `Open XML` кривой, но гибкий. Но что на столько кривой и интуитивно непонятный не ожидал.

Я кое как разобрался как получить координаты элементов на слайде

```
using (PresentationDocument doc = PresentationDocument.Open(@"d:\test.pptx", false))
{
    Slide firstSlide = doc.PresentationPart.SlideParts.First().Slide;
    CommonSlideData csd = firstSlide.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();
    var shapes = csd.Descendants<Shape>();

    foreach (var shape in shapes)
    {
        var t2d = shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D;
        if (t2d != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"X: {t2d.Offset.X}\nY: {t2d.Offset.Y}");
        }
    }
}
```

но не знаю **как узнать тип объекта**. В Interop получить этот тип было легко: у каждого Shape есть свойство Type, а куда его Open XML запрятал неизвестно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мною был задан аналогичный вопрос на форуме [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee7ccf72-8412-41a0-a316-e68deb19a930/how-get-shapes-type?forum=oxmlsdk) и ответ был таким

```
                Slide firstSlide = doc.PresentationPart.SlideParts.First().Slide;
                CommonSlideData csd = firstSlide.GetFirstChild<CommonSlideData>();
                var shapes = csd.Descendants<Shape>();

                foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
                {
                    A.PresetGeometry prst = shape.ShapeProperties.GetFirstChild<A.PresetGeometry>();
                    if (prst != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(prst.Preset);
                    }
                }
```

Правда хочеться отметить, что перечислитель [ST_ShapeType](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/t-a_ST_ShapeType.html) это больше **вид формы** нежели **тип объекта**. В `Open XML SDK` как понял, как таковой типизации элементов нет. Есть элемент `ShapeTree`, который содержит все дерево фигур.